# Replacing a knockout observable sent as a parameter

Tags: typescript, knockout.js, observer-pattern

I´m sending as a parameter two observables, and I want to replace these two with another observable; for some reason It doesn't get replaced but if I change the value on the observable it works.

```
private searchAndReplace = (flag: string, observable1: KnockoutObservable<string>, observable2: KnockoutObservable<string>) => {
        const itemFound = this.items.find((item) => item.flag === flag);
        if (itemFound) {
            observable1 = item.observableX;
            observable2 = item.observableY;
        }
    }
```

In this case I want to replace the variable sent with the item's observables but it seems not working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In this case I want to replace the variable sent...

You can't. The parameter you have is not connected to the variable that was used as the function argument in any way (JavaScript is stringly pass-by-value, it doesn't have pass-by-reference where a reference to the variable is passed into a function).

Obviously, if you just want to set the values of those observables, you could do that:

```
if (itemFound) {
    observable1(item.observableX());
    observable2(item.observableY());
}
```

you could also subscribe to the new observables, but you may end up with a lot of subscriptions:

```
// Probably a bad idea
if (itemFound) {
    item.observableX.subscribe(observable1);
    item.observableY.subscribe(observable2);
}
```

...but if you really want to replace the observables themselves, the best thing would probably be to have `searchAndReplace` *return* the pair of observables that should replace the existing ones:

```
private searchAndReplace = (flag: string, observable1: KnockoutObservable<string>, observable2: KnockoutObservable<string>) => {
    const itemFound = this.items.find((item) => item.flag === flag);
    if (itemFound) {
        return [item.observableX, item.observableY];
    }
    return [observable1, observable2];
}
```

Then where you call it, use destructuring assignment:

```
[original1, original2] = searchAndReplace("flag", original1, original2);
```